# Mapping dictionaries with AutoMapper

Tags: automapper

Given this these classes, how can I map a dictionary of them?

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class TestClassDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


Mapper.CreateMap<TestClass, TestClassDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Dictionary<string, TestClass>, 
                  Dictionary<string, TestClassDto>>();

var testDict = new Dictionary<string, TestClass>();
var testValue = new TestClass() {Name = "value1"};
testDict.Add("key1", testValue);

var mappedValue = Mapper.Map<TestClass, TestClassDto>(testValue);

var mappedDict = Mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, TestClass>, 
                            Dictionary<string, TestClassDto>>(testDict);
```

Mapping one of them, mappedValue in this case, works fine.

Mapping a dictionary of them ends up with no entries in the destination object.

What am I doing worng?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem you are having is because AutoMapper is struggling to map the **contents** of the Dictionary. You have to think what it is a store of - in this case **KeyValuePairs**.

If you try create a mapper for the KeyValuePair combination you will quickly work out that you can't directly as the **Key property doesn't have a setter**.

AutoMapper gets around this though by allowing you to Map using the constructor.

```cs
/* Create the map for the base object - be explicit for good readability */
Mapper.CreateMap<TestClass, TestClassDto>()
      .ForMember( x => x.Name, o => o.MapFrom( y => y.Name ) );

/* Create the map using construct using rather than ForMember */
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, TestClass>, KeyValuePair<string, TestClassDto>>()
      .ConstructUsing( x => new KeyValuePair<string, TestClassDto>( x.Key, 
                                                                    x.Value.MapTo<TestClassDto>() ) );

var testDict = new Dictionary<string, TestClass>();
var testValue = new TestClass()
{
    Name = "value1"
};
testDict.Add( "key1", testValue );

/* Mapped Dict will have your new KeyValuePair in there */
var mappedDict = Mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, TestClass>,
Dictionary<string, TestClassDto>>( testDict );
```

Comment: Note that the second ConstructUsing bit uses the first map to do its thing.

Comment: in my test case it started to work even without using `ConstructUsing` just after adding `CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, TestClass>, KeyValuePair<string, TestClassDto>>()`

Comment: Sweet, might have changed in the last 7 years :)

Comment: You don't even need the KeyValuePair mapping (at least not with the current version) - in fact, you don't need the Dictionary -> DIctionary mapping *at all*. Just the TestClass->TestClassDTO will do. It's the explicit Dictionary->DIctionary mapping that results in an empty DIctionary. AutoMapper implicitly supports closed generic type mappings. (Yes I know this question is over seven years old ;) )

Answer (score 4):

AutoMapper has changed a bit so it looks more like:

```
CreateMap<Thing, ThingDto>()
     .ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Thing, KeyValuePair<int, ThingDto>>()
     .ConstructUsing((t, ctx) => new KeyValuePair<int, ThingDto>(t.id, ctx.Mapper.Map<ThingDto>(t)));
```

Comment: Check the @oflahero's comment.

Comment: His comment nor anyone else's references the current version of ConstructUsing that passes two arguments to the func (t,ctx) where t is the ThingDto type and ctx is the ResolutionContext.

TMappingExpression ConstructUsing(Func<TSource, ResolutionContext, TDestination> ctor)

Comment: Yes, because it's not relevant here.

Comment: How is the updated and correct syntax not relevant?

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu I wish I had of read Skychan 's answer before I wasted an hour or two trying to get the original solution and comment to work. It's very relevant

Comment: Actually this is worse than manual mapping. It's obfuscated manual mapping. It completely defeats AM's purpose. So really, you either learn to use AM properly or you do it by hand.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu please help us understand what alternative way we can use AM in this case. You may have a point that we should just use manual mapping instead of this, I'll keep that in mind. I'm just curious if you know another way of using AM properly to accomplish this very situation. Mapping dictionaries must be a very common thing to map and we would all benefit by learning here.

Comment: The tests are [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/UnitTests/Dictionaries.cs).

Comment: Also http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping.html.