# AutoMapper Dictionary Flattening

Tags: automapper

I've got a `Dictionary<User, bool>`

User is as follows:

```cs
 public class User {
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Avatar { get; set;
}
```

The second type, bool, indicates whether this user is a friend of the logged in User.
I want to flatten this Dictionary into a `List<UserDto`> UserDto is defined as:

```cs
public class UserDto {
   public string Username { get; set; }
   public string Avatar { get; set; }
   public bool IsFriend { get; set; }
}
```

`IsFriend` represents the value of the dictionary.

How can I do this?

Comment: If anyone can give me a method that actually uses automapper, I will change the answer on the question!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should be able to do this with just one mapping<sup>1</sup>:

You need to map a `KeyValuePair<User, bool>` to `UserDto`. This is necessary for AutoMapper to be able to map the contents of the dictionary to the contents of the `List<T>` we're ultimately creating (more of an explanation can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5995167/497356)).

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<User, bool>, UserDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Username, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key.UserName))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Avatar, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key.Avatar))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsFriend, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

Then, use the mapping in your `.Map` call:

```cs
Mapper.Map<Dictionary<User, bool>, List<UserDto>>(...);
```

You don't need to map the collections themselves, as AutoMapper can handle mapping the `Dictionary` to a `List` as long as you've mapped the *contents* of the collections to each other (in our case, `KeyValuePair<User, bool>` to `UserDto`).

---

**Edit**: Here's another solution that doesn't require mapping every `User` property to `UserDto`:

```cs
Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<User, bool>, UserDto>()
    .ConstructUsing(src => Mapper.Map<User, UserDto>(src.Key))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.IsFriend, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value));
```

<sup>1</sup><sub>Using AutoMapper 2.0</sub>

Comment: This solution requires that any time I add a property to User & UserDto I need to change the mapping.  I'd rather have a solution that doesn't require individual properties to be mapped. Its not how automapper is supposed to work.

Comment: If "it's not how automapper is supposed to work" then why does the API even supply a `.ForMember` method? Nevertheless, I'll attempt a more "automatic" solution.

Comment: @reach4thelasers: I've added another solution that I think might be a little more automappery

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late to the game, yet this seems to be a more generic solution for mapping a dictionary to a .Net type(simple) using automapper

```
public static IMappingExpression<Dictionary<string, string>, TDestination> ConvertFromDictionary<TDestination>(
        this IMappingExpression<Dictionary<string, string>, TDestination> exp)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo pi in typeof(TDestination).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic))
    {
        exp.ForMember(propertyName, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(r => r[propertyName]));
    }
    return exp;
}
```

Use it like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Dictionary<string, string>, TDestination>().ConvertFromDictionary();
```

where TDestination can a .NET simple type. For complex types, you could supply a Func/Action delegate and map using that function.(Inside the above for-each)

Eg.

```
if (customPropNameMapFunc != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(customPropNameMapFunc(propertyName)))
{
   exp.ForMember(propertyName, cfg => cfg.MapFrom(r => r[customPropNameMapFunc(propertyName)]));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For something simple like this, a quick LINQ query will do.  Assuming `dict` is your `Dictionary<User,bool>`:

```
var conv = from kvp in dict
            select new UserDto
                    {
                        Avatar = kvp.Key.Avatar,
                        IsFriend = kvp.Value,
                        Username = kvp.Key.Username
                    };
```