# Map a dictionary's values to a list using AutoMapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a Database Object which has a dictionary of properties which I need to map to a list object within a new object. My structure (simplified) looks like this:

```
public class DbObject { // The source
  public Dictionary<string, DbCustomProperty> customProperties;
}

public class DbCustomProperty {
  public string Key;
  public string Value;
}



public class DTOObject { // The destination
  public List<DTOCustomProperty> DTOCustomProperties;
}

public class DTOCustomProperty {
  public string Key;
  public string Value;
}
```

As you can see, I would like to map DbObject (the source) onto a DTOObject (the destination). The problem is that my DBObject contains a dictionary where the values are the property that I've like to map into a list.

eg. dBObject.CustomProperties.Values --> dtoObject.CustomProperties

Can this be acheieved through AutoMapper?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AutoMapper Dictionary Flattening](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10519460/automapper-dictionary-flattening)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<IGrouping<string, DbCustomProperty>, DTOCustomProperty>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Key))
            .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Value)));
```