# Automapper Map from an object to a dictionary key value pair

Tags: automapper, key-value

Can I map a single object to a key value pair dictionary with the field name in the object as Key and the value of the field as Value. Thanks.

Comment: Will you know the property names ahead of time? As in do you want this to be dynamic for any given class?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I will know the property names ahead of time.

Comment: Check this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995167/mapping-dictionaries-with-automapper