# How can I pass a constructor parameter to an implicit Dictionary mapping using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper

Let's say I have a `TestClass` to `TestClassModel` mapping.

Without any other mappings declared, I can already map a `Dictionary<string,TestClass>` to a `Dictionary<string,TestClassModel>`.

Imagine though that the `Dictionary<string,TestClass>` had been initialized using `new Dictionary<string,TestClass>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`. This allows case-insensitive lookups.

How can the StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase constructor parameter be preserved in the mapped Dictionary? I've tried an explicit Dictionary->Dictionary mapping with `.ForCtorParam`, but that just results in an empty destination Dictionary (as you would then have to add KeyValuePair mappings.)

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/KYQNWT

Comment: After setting up the mapping for the dictionary, you've overwritten AutoMappers internal Dictionary mapper.  You'll notice that `_dt` will be case-insensitive however no values are mapped because now I doesn't know how to map [`KeyValuePair` because it's setters are readonly.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995167/mapping-dictionaries-with-automapper)  That being said I haven't had much luck getting the KeyValuePair mapping working.

Comment: That's the issue Erik; you can get yourself a case-insensitive mapped dictionary, but it's empty. At that rate, you'd be better off rolling your own mapper altogether. So I was just wondering if there was some crafty AutoMapper method that I've overlooked :)

Comment: You should map into an existing dictionary which you create with StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu: but I want it to happen automatically - say, the Dictionary is a property of another mapped object. I'd like the mapping to automatically happen for the Dictionary property without having to specify it manually. If possible, I understand it may not be.

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. But you have to provide the dictionary instance yourself. Pass an existing destination, set UseDestinationValue for that property, MapFrom new dictionary. There are options. Better than the answer bellow.

Comment: I never want to pass an existing DIctionary destination though - that's the point. Unless it gets created in a lambda somehow as specified somewhere in the configuration. Otherwise I'd be quicker just writing my own mapper for this case!

Comment: Of course. But I think you should be reading the docs.

Comment: I tried, but gave up after spending as much time as I would have just rolling my own mapper. Your comprehension must be better than mine!

Comment: I just think 'create DIctionary & KeyValuePair mappings' -> 'do explicit DIctionary mapping' -> 'create destination model' -> 'set destination Dictionary with mapped value' -> 'do destination mapping with UseDestinationValue set for the dictionary property' - is far more laborious than it's worth. YMMV.

Comment: And I completely agree, but without some research, I don't see how you could understand how it's done.

Answer (score 1):

I did get it working, but not sure why it doesn't work on DotNetFiddle.  If I run it in my own app it works just fine.  I left in other things I tested for.

```
  Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
  {
    cfg.CreateMap<TestClass, TestClassModel>()
      .ForMember(d => d._F1, s => s.MapFrom(o => o.F1));

    cfg.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<string, TestClass>, KeyValuePair<string, TestClassModel>>()
      .ConstructUsing(x => new KeyValuePair<string, TestClassModel>(x.Key, Mapper.Map<TestClassModel>(x.Value)));

    cfg.CreateMap(typeof(Dictionary<,>), typeof(Dictionary<string, TestClassModel>))
      //.ForCtorParam("collection", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, TestClassModel>>>(src)))
      //.ForCtorParam("comparer", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
      .ConstructUsing(src => new Dictionary<string, TestClassModel>(Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, TestClassModel>>>(src), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
  });
```

If you're going to run this in any type of real environment I highly recommend using the [instanced type of automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Static-and-Instance-API.html).

Comment: Not working for me I'm afraid Erik, either in fiddle or VS. Compiler complains that it can't convert between IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string,TestClassModel>> and Dictionary<string,TestClassModel> in the 'new Dictionary(...) ' constructor call.

Comment: I tried  .ConstructUsing(src => new Dictionary<string, TestClassModel>
                    (Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, TestClassModel>>>(src).ToDictionary(
                       s => s.Key, v => v.Value
                        ), 
                    StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase), which satisfies the compiler, but at runtime a 'no coercion operator is defined for...' error is thrown. Never mind, don't want to spend too much time on this anyway!