# How to map Object to KeyValuePair<char, string> using AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper, key-value, asp.net-core-3.1, automapper-9

I'm trying to map my object model to a `KeyValuePair<char, string>` but my results are `KeyValuePairs` where Key = null and Value = null.

What's the correct way to do this?

---

Model:

```cs
public class Symbol
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int TemplateId { get; set; }
        public Template Template { get; set; }
        public char Letter { get; set; }
        public string ImgSource { get; set; }
    }
```

Profile:

```cs
    public class AutoMapping : Profile
    {
        public AutoMapping()
        {
            CreateMap<Symbol, KeyValuePair<object, object>>()
                      .ForMember(dest => dest.Key, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Letter))
                      .ForMember(dest => dest.Value, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ImgSource))
                      .ReverseMap();
                      
        }
    }
```

Attempt:

```cs
                using (_dbContext)
                {
                    var q = await _dbContext.Symbol
                        .Where(x => x.TemplateId == templateId)
                        .OrderBy(x => x.Letter)
                        .Select(x => _mapper.Map<KeyValuePair<char, string>>(x))
                        .ToListAsync();

                    //return _mapper.Map<List<KeyValuePair<char, string>>>(q);
                    return q;
                }
```

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5995167/mapping-dictionaries-with-automapper

Comment: @Syntiara Thanks! Using "ConstructUsing" worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by using the following :

```cs
CreateMap<Symbol, KeyValuePair<char, string>>()
                .ConstructUsing(sym => new KeyValuePair<char, string>(sym.Letter, sym.ImgSource));
```